# How to use factorisation $z^{n}-1$ to prove the summation goes to zero?

Tags: complex-numbers, induction, proof-explanation

I need to show that $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})+\sin(\frac{4\pi}{n})+...+\sin(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n})=0$ for $n>1$ but specifically using the fact that $z^{n}-1=(z-1)(1+z+z^{2}+...+z^{n-1})$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I've proved that equality by induction but I do not know how to incorporate it what I need to show.
Thinking it might have something to do with $n^{th}$ roots of unity.

Anything would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1. From the given factorisation, you deduce, not only the sum of the geometric series, but also, closely related, that
   $$z+z^2+\dots +z^{n-1}=z(1+z+\dots+z^{n-2})=\frac{z(z^{n-1}-1)}{z-1}.$$
2. Setting $z=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}n}$, $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})+\sin(\frac{4\pi}{n})+...+\sin(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n})$ is the imaginary part of
   $$z+z^2+\dots+z^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})+...+\sin(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n})$ is the imaginary part of $1+\zeta+\zeta^2+...+\zeta^{n-1}$ where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

$\zeta-1\ne 0$, but $\zeta^n=1$, so using the factorization you get the desired result.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the fact that a complex number can be written in that form!? Any other way to show the same result?

Comment: You could probably use De Moivre's formula:

$(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n=\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$

Comment: Strange limitation, since it's really the simplest and clearest way to prove this equation. If you need to go as far as proving De Moivre's formula above, start by proving $(\cos x + i \sin x)(\cos y + i \sin y) = \cos(x+y) + i \sin(x+y)$ for all real $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $$
I= 1+e^{i \frac{2\pi}{n}} + e^{i \frac{4\pi}{n}}+ ... + e^{i \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{k}}= \frac {(e^{i \frac{2\pi}{n}})^n -1}{e^{i \frac{2\pi}{n}} -1}
=0
$$

Thus, with $\sin x=\operatorname{Im }(e^{ix})$,

$$
\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}+ \sin\frac{4\pi}{n}+ ... + \sin\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}=\operatorname{Im} (I)=0
$$